# LinkButton in GridView non-clickable if it ends in a certain filetype

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview, linkbutton

How would I make this LinkButton in GridView non-clickable if it ends in a *.rpt filetype?

I'm not sure where and which conditions I should add.

Thanks in advance! 
Brett

LinkButton
.ascx code

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbFolderItem" CommandName="OpenFolder"     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlFileItem"></asp:Literal>
```

Code Behind
ascx.cs code

```
protected void gvFiles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var item = e.Row.DataItem as FileSystemItemCS;

        if (item.IsFolder)
        {
            var lbFolderItem = e.Row.FindControl("lbFolderItem") as LinkButton;
            lbFolderItem.Text = string.Format(@"<img src=""{0}"" alt="""" />&nbsp;{1}", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/folder.png"), item.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            var ltlFileItem = e.Row.FindControl("ltlFileItem") as Literal;
            if (this.CurrentFolder.StartsWith("~"))
                ltlFileItem.Text = string.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"" target=""_blank"">{1}</a>",
                        Page.ResolveClientUrl(string.Concat(this.CurrentFolder, "/", item.Name).Replace("//", "/")),
                        item.Name);
            else
                ltlFileItem.Text = item.Name;
        }
    }
}


protected void gvFiles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "OpenFolder")
    {
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), "..") == 0)
        {
            var currentFullPath = this.CurrentFolder;
            if (currentFullPath.EndsWith("\\") || currentFullPath.EndsWith("/"))
                currentFullPath = currentFullPath.Substring(0, currentFullPath.Length - 1);

            currentFullPath = currentFullPath.Replace("/", "\\");

            var folders = currentFullPath.Split("\\".ToCharArray());

            this.CurrentFolder = string.Join("\\", folders, 0, folders.Length - 1);
        }
        else
            this.CurrentFolder = Path.Combine(this.CurrentFolder, e.CommandArgument as string);


        PopulateGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "ends in an *.rpt filetype"?

Comment: Add a condition where any objects that contains the name .rpt that the link in not clickable.  A *.rpt file is a Crystal Reports filetype Thanks!

Comment: So your link button corresponds to a folder, and if in this folder there is a rpt file, you do not want folder link to be clickable? The best bet is to change this in your data source, so that to the data binding you already know if link should be clickable. No good going back and forth through the gridview analyzing its content

Comment: Thanks Andrei!  That logic worked!!